# How to SELECT Specific LAST NODE Value under repeating parent Node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Can Someone Please Give me [XPATH or template] where i need to get the value of the LAST ID .under root of name  Node where i need to consider name first four name only]

In the below example the  value that i need will be GREEN3 by considering only first 4 names and last id out of 4. Please provide me the code snippet

```
<NAMES>
  <NAME>
    <ID>GREEN1</ID>
  </NAME>
  <NAME>
    <ID2>GREEN6</ID2>
  </NAME>
  <NAME>
    <ID>GREEN2</ID>
  </NAME>
  <NAME>
    <ID>GREEN3</ID>
  </NAME>
  <NAME>
    <ID>GREEN4</ID>
  </NAME>
  <NAME>
    <ID2>GREEN5</ID2>
  </NAME>
</NAMES>
```

Comment: <NAMES> <NAME> <ID>GREEN1</ID> </NAME> <NAME> <ID2>GREEN6</ID2> </NAME> <NAME> <ID>GREEN2</ID> </NAME> <NAME> <ID>GREEN3</ID> </NAME> <NAME> <ID>GREEN4</ID> </NAME> <NAME> <ID2>GREEN5</ID2> </NAME> </NAMES>

Comment: name[position<=4 and ID]/ID under froreach:-NAMES/Name but no use i am getting all the values i need only one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear. If you want to consider only the first four names, and get the last ID in this group, then you could use:

```
select="(/NAMES/NAME[position() &lt;=4]/ID)[last()]"
```

In the following example:

```
<NAMES>
  <NAME>
    <ID>a</ID>
  </NAME>
  <NAME>
    <ID>b</ID>
  </NAME>
  <NAME>
    <ID>c</ID>
  </NAME>
  <NAME>
    <ID>d</ID>
  </NAME>
  <NAME>
    <ID>e</ID>
  </NAME>
</NAMES>
```

the above expression selects:

```
<ID>d</ID>
```

In this example:

```
<NAMES>
  <NAME>
    <ID>a</ID>
  </NAME>
  <NAME>
    <ID>b</ID>
  </NAME>
  <NAME>
    <ID>c</ID>
  </NAME>
  <NAME>
    <IDx>d</IDx>
  </NAME>
  <NAME>
    <ID>e</ID>
  </NAME>
</NAMES>
```

the selection is:

```
<ID>c</ID>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have provided you can try something like this

```
  <xsl:template match="NAMES" >
    <xsl:value-of select="NAME[4]/ID"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Since only first four names are under consideration and you need the 4th NAME id you can directly go to that node and get that value.

Comment: Thanks saurav..I am not looking for ID undue fourth name exactly ..I am looking for ID occurres last in first four name ..your answer will return only 4th name ID ..if there is any ..that's not what my scenario was ..apart from that there could be elements like id_2 undur name

Comment: what happens if there are no 4 name nodes?

Comment: In other words i need to get the last ID value of of first 4 name (name can be4.. 3 ..2..or ..1) apart from that under name there is a possibility of ID or ID2 but I need to get last set of ID from any name(<=4)

Comment: Yes there could be a possibility of <4 name but we need to consider first 4name if there are more name